# Spatial data mining algorithms about local business web services?

Tags: web-services, map

Do you know any research paper about spatial data mining algorithms to retrieve trends about local business services (such as google places.. etc)

let's say most rated restaurants this week.. etc ?

I need scientific material about it.

thanks

Comment: You might get success at the Stack Exchange site for statistics. The crowd might not be very "programmy" but you might strike a chord and/or get another path to check out. http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a *really* specific question - your best bet would be to inquire directly with [people who specialize in spatial data mining](http://www.academia.edu/People/Spatial_Data_Mining_Data_Mining_) and possibly with companies which provide local business/restaurant data to see what's out there.

(Note that sites like [Yelp](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation) and [Google Places](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) have API's which might come in handy if you plan to conduct any original research)

Comment: I'd also add that Bing or Live or whatever it's called these days also has something similar to Google Places. Facebook is also in this space as well.